# IE10 - Hebrew text reversed - how to fix?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, hebrew

I am facing issue with Hebrew language in IE10 and Firefox. Some part of the text gets reversed as mentioned below:
(79 הכול 1 - 50) מתוך

The number 79 should be after הכול with a closing bracket. Its working fine in IE11.

Tried the steps given in [IE10 - RTL reversed - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665719/ie10-rtl-reversed-how-to-fix) however its not working.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but anyway, try enclosing your text in a tag with `dir="rtl"` attribute, e.g. `<div dir="rtl">...</div>"`.